# Remove shadow from toolbar when fragment with viewpager is launched

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My `MainActivity` implements `NavigationView`, so mostly the whole contents of the screen are inside `FrameLayout`. In one of the `Fragments`, I have a `ViewPager`, I want that when that `Fragment` is launched, the `elevation` from `Toolbar` gets removed, and otherwise gets re-added.

My target API is 29, and I don't care for the support of older versions.

`activity_main.xml`

```xml
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`fragment_view_pager.xml`

```xml
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabs_vp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest answer, in the `ViewPager` fragment:

```
private var myElevation: Float? = null

override fun onCreateView(/* params */) {
    // other code
    myElevation = activity!!.app_bar_id.elevation
    activity!!.app_bar_id.elevation = 0f
}    

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    activity!!.app_bar_id.elevation = myElevation!!
}
```

In this way, the elevation is `0` only when the `ViewPager` Fragment is active.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
           android:id="@+id/appcompat_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <include
               layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

       <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="gone"
          <include
             layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

       </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I have taken two things -

1. AppBarLayout(which has Toolbar inside it) - android:id="@+id/appcompat_layout"
2. LinearLayout(which has Toolbar inside it) - 
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"

Now what you have to do is, when your Fragment is launched make the toolbar_layout visible and appcompat_layout invisible else vice-versa.

Initially during the Activity launch, keep appcompat_layout visible and toolbar_layout invisible

Cheers!

Comment: Then, the elevation would never be shown, I don't want that

Comment: Okay, understood. Checking the issue.

Comment: That seems fine in a way, but for that I have to edit code in all of the fragments, I have a lot of fragments in my app, so is there something else that could be done?

Comment: You are loading multiple fragments in the view pager which is in the same activity. Again I think you are initializing all your fragments from the same activity. So you get the visibility flag in the same activity.

Comment: And make visible and invisible from your activity is very easy because you are changing the activity layout.

Comment: Yes, activity is one but how will I know when the fragment viewpager has been exited?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195749/discussion-between-zachary-and-akshdeep-singh).

Answer (score 0):

for remove elevation

```
  toolbar.setElevation(0f);
```

for add elevation

```
toolbar.setElevation(your float number);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity XML, just add **app:elevation="0dp"** attribute to AppBarLayout. This will cause no elevation to all fragments under this activity. Here, I use a frame layout for the fragment containers.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

               <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```